# empty output file on complete search task

Tags: c++, c++11, search

I am working on a complete search problem, and have looked through the code, but could not figure out why my program keeps coming in with an empty output file error. Could anyone please help me find why this is happening? The problem statement is below, and then after that is my code.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**: Palindromes are numbers that read the same forwards as backwards. The number 12321 is a typical palindrome.

Given a number base B (2 <= B <= 20 base 10), print all the integers N (1 <= N <= 300 base 10) such that the square of N is palindromic when expressed in base B; also print the value of that palindromic square. Use the letters 'A', 'B', and so on to represent the digits 10, 11, and so on.

Print both the number and its square in base B.

**MY CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//utility function to raise number to a power
int power(int first, int second)
{
    int total = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < second; i++)
    {
        total *= first;
    }
    return total;
}

//convert the number to the proper base
int convert(string num, int base1)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = num.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        sum += num[i] * power(base1, num.size() - i);
    return sum;
}

//test if converted number is a palindrome
bool is_pal(int number)
{
    //if the #ofdigits is even
    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        int mid = (to_string(number).size()) / 2;
        string str_num = to_string(number);
        string half1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
            half1 += str_num[i];
        string half2;
        for (int i = str_num.size()-1; i > mid-1; i--)
            half2 += str_num[i];
        if (half1 == half2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    //if the #ofdigits is odd
    else
    {
        int mid1 = (to_string(number).size() - 1) / 2;
        int mid2 = (to_string(number).size() + 1) / 2;
        string str_num = to_string(number);
        string half1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mid1; i++)
        {
            half1 += str_num[i];
        }
        string half2;
        for (int i = str_num.size()-1; i > mid2-1; i--)
        {
            half2 += str_num[i];
        }
        if (half1 == half2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("palsquare.out");
    ifstream fin("palsquare.in");
    int base;
    fin >> base;

    for (int i = 1; i < 300; i++)
    {
        if (is_pal(convert(to_string((power(i, 2))), base)))
        {
            fout << convert(to_string(i), base) << " " << convert(to_string(power(i, 2)), base) << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you test `is_pal(...)`?

Comment: What do you mean by this? I first converted the square of the original number to the correct base, and then put that into is_pal to test if it is a palindrome.

Comment: A note on `convert`,  all those `pow`s are going to be brutally slow and imprecise. `pow` operates on floating point numbers and you may find the results are off just a little bit (like 24.99999999 instead of 25) and then get rounded down. You can write your own function that computes purely integer powers [or you can use `std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I will write my own power function. But, does anyone know why the output is empty? Thanks!

Comment: What Beta is getting at is have you tested `is_pal` on it's own with known values to ensure that it works?

Comment: I am doing that now... and I will tell the results soon.

Comment: Example, in base 2 101010101 is a palindrome. In decimal this number is 341, so if you call `is_pal(341)`, do you get true? Start with proving the math, then worry about writing files.

Comment: thank you, I will work to verify this, and will get back asap with results (probably in around 1 hour).

Comment: by the way, when I call is_pal I am directly feeding it the argument in the changed base form, by calling convert on the decimal number and then putting the result into is_pal.

Comment: I figured out a big part of it: my convert function was actually converting from the changed base to decimal form, but it wasn't doing even that correctly! I will work to fix this now, and back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, calculate your result once and then use the calculated result if you need to output it. Calling `convert(to_string((pow(i, 2))` twice is terribly inefficient. An added bonus of caching intermediate results is that you can more easily see them in the debugger.

Comment: I am going to edit the post to show my updated code with my new power function, and comments to explain the sections for anyone that would need it. NOTE: the convert function is still incorrect, I will be working on this right after.

Comment: Your function to test if a number is a palindrom is terribly complicated: std::equal(str.begin(), str.end(),str.rbegin()) should be enough. And don't use pow(); what's wrong with i*i ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comments, the usual pattern for converting a number to base B is of the form:

```
std::string convert_base(int B, int num)
{
    assert(B>1&&num>=0);
    char const digits[] ="0123456789AB...Z";
    std::vector<char> str;
    do
    {
        int const d = num%B;
        num /= B;
        str.push_back(digits[d]);
    } while(num);

    return std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
}
```

Complete answer is then:

```
bool is_pal(std::string const & str)
{
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), std.crbegin());
}

int const pow2_i = i*i;
std::string const pow2_baseB = convert_base(B, pow2_i);
if(is_pal(pow2_baseB)) ...
```

Comment: The real genius of this approach is it takes a number and returns a string. The asker has numbers (1 through 300) as inputs and strings are much easier to test for palindromic behaviour (test that the outermost characters match and then work your way in to the middle)